# How to get a container's info when using rhuss/docker-maven-plugin?

Tags: docker, maven-plugin

How to get a container's info (e.g.: the ip) using the [docker-maven-plugin by rhuss](https://github.com/rhuss/docker-maven-plugin) (groupId: "org.jolokia")?

Their [changelog](https://github.com/rhuss/docker-maven-plugin/blob/e265fd2ec5b0514a8699f3f4ad1afcae687fc58b/doc/changelog.md) mentions "Allow the container's host ip to be bound to a maven property and exported" on version 0.13.3. But apparently it's not documented how to do it.

Comment: Maybe contribute with the `docker inspect`? So you'll get far more than just the ip. Otherwise I don't really know, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found instead that the plugin can have docker forward a port in the container to a random (available, I assume) port on the host. So you can access applications in the container with `<host-ip>:<mapped-port>`

As in the [sample project](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/blob/master/samples/data-jolokia-demo/pom.xml):
On the plugin declaration, under `<image>` and then `<run>`, declare a `<port>your.key:8080</port>`. The plugin will set the property `your.key` with the random port it had assigned to the container.

I found this to work on Maven 3, but not 2. Also my IntelliJ can't figure out that `your.key` is valid and marks it red.